# Why was this question about whether airlines check the weight of the passengers' clothes closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The question [Do airlines sometimes check the weight of the passengers' clothes?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168872/1810) was  closed as off-topic, whereas there exist [many](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhand-luggage%5D+weight) questions pertaining to item weight when checking-in or boarding that are open and upvoted. Why was it closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice if people who have voted to close would take a voice. Because closing on-topic question as off-topic because there's something wrong but other close reasons are hard to match is simply lazy.

I feel your question is much to broad. With over 5000 airlines worldwide, and you asking for anecdotal evidence instead of regular policy, it's impossible that anyone can give a reasonable answer. It's impossible anyone knows enough people to cover all those 5000 airlines with enough statistical data to know for sure that none of them is doing so.

On the other hand, even one single case would be 'yes' to your question. If only 1% of airlines are doing that, you'll have at least 50 answers, each of them correct, only one can be accepted.

AFAIR there was a close reason for list questions, but then it was replaced with too broad, and finally, with need more focus.

Comment: Thanks, the spirit of the question is whether any airline checks for it, not listing all companies who check. If I'm aware that some companies do check, then I'll check the policy of the specific airlines I'm flying with (if I happen to have voluminous clothes).